# Abnormal dartfmt behavior. What's wrong?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use dartfmt(via the latest intellij idea) it formats my code like this:
[Picture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YvY1.png)

But normally code should look something like this:  [Picture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMzDg.png)

Am I wrong and the formatting from picture-1 is good or there is something wrong with dartfmt tool?

```
if (antivirus.first != 'Windows Defender' &&
              (Directory(antivirus[2]).existsSync() ||
                  File(antivirus[2]).existsSync() ||
                  Directory(antivirus[3]).existsSync() ||
                  File(antivirus[3]).existsSync())) {
            print(1);
          }
```

Comment: Picture-1 looks like how dartfmt usually format this kind of things. I have never seen Picture-2 in my code which is automatically formatted with dartfmt. It looks like how Idea would format the code using its own formatter?

Comment: 2nd code i've formatted on my own. I don't think the first one is correct. Maybe there is some way to fix it?

Comment: dartfmt does not have much configuration since the philosophy is that all code formatted with dartfmt should look mostly the same. Read first this and then you can consider if you want to fill out a bug report: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#i-dont-like-the-output